# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4

Tags: java, arraylist

Приложение вылетает. Не могу полностью понять в чем проблема. В logcat пишет:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 4, Size: 4
at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
at ru.bladegames.rustate.gui.dialogs.Dialog.loadTabList(Dialog.java:152)
```

код:

```
private void loadTabList(String content) {
    String[] strings = content.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (this.mCurrentDialogTypeId == 5 && i == 0) {
            String[] headers = strings[i].split("\t");
            for (int j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                this.mHeadersList.get(j).setText(Utils.transfromColors(headers[j]));
                this.mHeadersList.get(j).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            this.mRowsList.add(strings[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

полный код:

```
public class Dialog {
private static final int DIALOG_LEFT_BTN_ID = 1;
private static final int DIALOG_RIGHT_BTN_ID = 0;
private static final int DIALOG_STYLE_INPUT = 1;
private static final int DIALOG_STYLE_LIST = 2;
private static final int DIALOG_STYLE_MSGBOX = 0;
private static final int DIALOG_STYLE_PASSWORD = 3;
private static final int DIALOG_STYLE_TABLIST = 4;
private static final int DIALOG_STYLE_TABLIST_HEADER = 5;
private final TextView mCaption;
private final TextView mContent;
private int mCurrentDialogId = -1;
private int mCurrentDialogTypeId = -1;
private String mCurrentInputText = "";
private int mCurrentListItem = -1;
private final CustomRecyclerView mCustomRecyclerView;
private final ArrayList<TextView> mHeadersList;
private final CustomEditText mInput;
private final ConstraintLayout mInputLayout;
private final ConstraintLayout mLeftBtn;
private final ConstraintLayout mListLayout;
private final ConstraintLayout mMainLayout;
private final ScrollView mMsgBoxLayout;
private final ConstraintLayout mRightBtn;
private ArrayList<String> mRowsList;

public Dialog(Activity activity) {
    this.mMainLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_main);
    this.mCaption = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_caption);
    this.mContent = (TextView) activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_text);
    ConstraintLayout findViewById1 = activity.findViewById(R.id.sd_button_positive);
    this.mLeftBtn = findViewById1;
    ConstraintLayout findViewById2 = activity.findViewById(R.id.sd_button_negative);
    this.mRightBtn = findViewById2;
    this.mInputLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_input_layout);
    this.mListLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_list_layout);
    this.mMsgBoxLayout = (ScrollView) activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_text_layout);
    this.mInput = (CustomEditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_input);
    this.mCustomRecyclerView = (CustomRecyclerView) activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_list_recycler);
    findViewById1.setOnClickListener(view -> sendDialogResponse(1));
    findViewById2.setOnClickListener(view -> sendDialogResponse(0));
    this.mRowsList = new ArrayList<>();
    this.mHeadersList = new ArrayList<>();
    ConstraintLayout mHeadersLayout = activity.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_tablist_row);
    for (int i = 0; i < mHeadersLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
        this.mHeadersList.add((TextView) mHeadersLayout.getChildAt(i));
    }
    this.mInput.setOnEditorActionListener((textView, i, keyEvent) -> {
        Editable editableText;
        if ((i != 6 && i != 5) || (editableText = this.mInput.getText()) == null) {
            return false;
        }
        this.mCurrentInputText = editableText.toString();
        return false;
    });
    this.mInput.setOnClickListener(view ->
    {
        this.mInput.requestFocus();
        ((InputMethodManager) NvEventQueueActivity.getInstance().getSystemService("input_method")).showSoftInput(this.mInput, 1);
    });
    Utils.HideLayout(this.mMainLayout, false);
}

public void show(int dialogId, int dialogTypeId, String caption, String content, String leftBtnText, String rightBtnText) {
    clearDialogData();
    this.mCurrentDialogId = dialogId;
    this.mCurrentDialogTypeId = dialogTypeId;
    if (dialogTypeId == 0) {
        this.mInputLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.mListLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.mMsgBoxLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else if(dialogTypeId == 1 || dialogTypeId == 3)
    {
        this.mInputLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); // выполняется инпут
        this.mMsgBoxLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.mListLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
    else
    {
        this.mInputLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        this.mMsgBoxLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // LIST, TABLIST, TABLIST_HEADER
        this.mListLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        loadTabList(content);
        ArrayList<String> fixFieldsForDialog = Utils.fixFieldsForDialog(this.mRowsList);
        this.mRowsList = fixFieldsForDialog;
        DialogAdapter adapter = new DialogAdapter(fixFieldsForDialog, this.mHeadersList);
        adapter.setOnClickListener((i, str) -> { this.mCurrentListItem = i;
        this.mCurrentInputText = str; });
        adapter.setOnDoubleClickListener(() -> sendDialogResponse(1));
        this.mCustomRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager((Context) NvEventQueueActivity.getInstance()));
        this.mCustomRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (dialogTypeId != 2) {
            CustomRecyclerView customRecyclerView = this.mCustomRecyclerView;
            adapter.getClass();
            customRecyclerView.post(() -> adapter.updateSizes());
        }
    }
    this.mCaption.setText(Utils.transfromColors(caption));
    this.mContent.setText(Utils.transfromColors(content));
    ((TextView) this.mLeftBtn.getChildAt(0)).setText(Utils.transfromColors(leftBtnText));
    ((TextView) this.mRightBtn.getChildAt(0)).setText(Utils.transfromColors(rightBtnText));
    if (rightBtnText.equals("")) { this.mRightBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE); }
    else { this.mRightBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); }
    Utils.ShowLayout(this.mMainLayout, true);
}

public void hideWithoutReset() { Utils.HideLayout(this.mMainLayout, false); }

public void showWithOldContent() { Utils.ShowLayout(this.mMainLayout, false); }

public void sendDialogResponse(int btnId) {
    if (!this.mCurrentInputText.equals(this.mInput.getText().toString())) { this.mCurrentInputText = this.mInput.getText().toString(); }
    ((InputMethodManager) NvEventQueueActivity.getInstance().getSystemService("input_method")).hideSoftInputFromWindow(this.mInput.getWindowToken(), 0);
    byte[] str = null;
    try { str = this.mCurrentInputText.getBytes("windows-1251"); }
    catch(UnsupportedEncodingException e) { }
    NvEventQueueActivity.getInstance().sendDialogResponse(btnId, this.mCurrentDialogId, this.mCurrentListItem, str);
    Utils.HideLayout(this.mMainLayout, true);
}

private void loadTabList(String content) {
    String[] strings = content.split("\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        if (this.mCurrentDialogTypeId == 5 && i == 0) {
            String[] headers = strings[i].split("\t");
            for (int j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
                this.mHeadersList.get(j).setText(Utils.transfromColors(headers[j]));
                this.mHeadersList.get(j).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } else {
            this.mRowsList.add(strings[i]);
        }
    }
}

private void clearDialogData() {
    this.mInput.setText("");
    this.mCurrentDialogId = -1;
    this.mCurrentDialogTypeId = -1;
    this.mCurrentListItem = -1;
    this.mRowsList.clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < this.mHeadersList.size(); i++) {
        this.mHeadersList.get(i).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}

public void onHeightChanged(int height) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) this.mMainLayout.getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, height);
    this.mMainLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
}
}
```

Также добавляю DialogAdapter.java, думаю он пригодится:

```
public class DialogAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {
private int mCurrentSelectedPosition = 0;
private View mCurrentSelectedView;
private final ArrayList<TextView> mFieldHeaders;
private final ArrayList<String> mFieldTexts;
private final ArrayList<ArrayList<TextView>> mFields;
private OnClickListener mOnClickListener;
private OnDoubleClickListener mOnDoubleClickListener;

public interface OnClickListener {
    void onClick(int i, String str);
}

public interface OnDoubleClickListener {
    void onDoubleClick();
}

public DialogAdapter(ArrayList<String> fields, ArrayList<TextView> fieldHeaders) {
    this.mFieldTexts = fields;
    this.mFieldHeaders = fieldHeaders;
    this.mFields = new ArrayList<>();
}

public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rustate_dialog_item, parent, false));
}

public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    onBindViewHolder((ViewHolder) holder, position);
}

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    String[] headers = this.mFieldTexts.get(position).split("\t");
    ArrayList<TextView> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
        TextView field = holder.mFields.get(i);
        field.setText(Utils.transfromColors(headers[i].replace("\\t", "")));
        field.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        fields.add(field);
    }
    this.mFields.add(fields);
    if (this.mCurrentSelectedPosition == position) {
        ImageView imageView = holder.mFieldBg;
        this.mCurrentSelectedView = imageView;
        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.mOnClickListener.onClick(position, holder.mFields.get(0).getText().toString());
    } else {
        holder.mFieldBg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    holder.getView().setOnClickListener(view -> {
        if (this.mCurrentSelectedPosition != holder.getAdapterPosition()) {
            View view2 = this.mCurrentSelectedView;
            if (view2 != null) {
                view2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            this.mCurrentSelectedPosition = holder.getAdapterPosition();
            this.mCurrentSelectedView = holder.mFieldBg;
            holder.mFieldBg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.mOnClickListener.onClick(holder.getAdapterPosition(), holder.mFields.get(0).getText().toString());
            return;
        }
        OnDoubleClickListener onDoubleClickListener = this.mOnDoubleClickListener;
        if (onDoubleClickListener != null) {
            onDoubleClickListener.onDoubleClick();
        }
    });
}

public void updateSizes() {
    int[] max = new int[4];
    for (int i = 0; i < this.mFields.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < this.mFields.get(i).size(); j++) {
            int width = this.mFields.get(i).get(j).getWidth();
            if (max[j] < width) {
                max[j] = width;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i2 = 0; i2 < max.length; i2++) {
        int headerWidth = this.mFieldHeaders.get(i2).getWidth();
        Log.i("DIALOG", max[i2] + "\t" + ((Object) this.mFieldHeaders.get(i2).getText()) + MaskedEditText.SPACE + headerWidth);
        if (max[i2] < headerWidth) {
            max[i2] = headerWidth;
        }
    }
    for (int i3 = 0; i3 < this.mFields.size(); i3++) {
        for (int j2 = 0; j2 < this.mFields.get(i3).size(); j2++) {
            this.mFields.get(i3).get(j2).setWidth(max[j2]);
        }
    }
    for (int i4 = 0; i4 < this.mFieldHeaders.size(); i4++) {
        this.mFieldHeaders.get(i4).setWidth(max[i4]);
    }
}

public void setOnClickListener(OnClickListener onClickListener) {
    this.mOnClickListener = onClickListener;
}

public void setOnDoubleClickListener(OnDoubleClickListener onDoubleClickListener) {
    this.mOnDoubleClickListener = onDoubleClickListener;
}

public ArrayList<ArrayList<TextView>> getFields() {
    return this.mFields;
}

public int getItemCount() {
    return this.mFieldTexts.size();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView mFieldBg;
    public ArrayList<TextView> mFields = new ArrayList<>();
    private final View mView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        this.mView = itemView;
        this.mFieldBg = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_item_bg);
        ConstraintLayout field = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rustate_dialog_item_main);
        for (int i = 1; i < field.getChildCount(); i++) {
            this.mFields.add((TextView) field.getChildAt(i));
        }
    }

    public View getView() {
        return this.mView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `this.mHeadersList.get(j)` тут вы обращаетесь к элементу с индексом 4, а такого элемента в `this.mHeadersList` нет.

Comment: Для полного понимания проблемы добавьте код, в котором создаётся this.mHeadersList

Comment: добавил весь код диалога.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [исключение java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException javafx](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/854258/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-java-lang-indexoutofboundsexception-javafx)

Answer (score 0):

Index: 4, Size: 4

Это означает, в массиве 4 элемента. Индексация элементов в массивах начинается с нуля (0). Соответственно, индекс Вашего первого элемента "0", а индекс последного четвертого элемента "3".

length хранит в себе количество элементов. (В вашем случае 4 элемента)

Когда вы просите элемента с 4им индексом (его там нет, у четвертого элекмента индекс: 3) java выбрасывает исключение.

РЕШЕНИЕ: Сделайте "length-1" в цикле!

Comment: в цикле идёт обращение по индексу к какому-то массиву и к какому-то листу, причём ни из чего не следует, что их длины одинаковы. Нужно или делать их одной длины, или обрабатывать как случай, более длинного листа, так и случай более длинного массива.

Comment: я уже пробовал так делать, не помогает.

Answer (score 0):

Причину нашел! Проблема была в mHeadersLayout, тоесть там в самом лайоте создавалось 4 строки, когда в моем диалоге должно быть 5! Добавил строку, проблема решена! [image: решил проблему над которой работал пол дня]